# communication between two separate component angular 2

Tags: angular, components, directive

in angular 2 I want to make a communication between two separate components via a service but they are not children and parent.
Service component:

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
@Injectable()
export class SignUpService {
private openDialog = new Subject<any>();
openDialogObservable$ = this.openDialog.asObservable();
constructor(){}
public open(data: any) {
if (data) {
  this.openDialog.next(data);
  }
 }
}
```

SignUpComponent:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {SignUpService} from "../services/signup-service.service";
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
@Component({
selector: 'signup',
templateUrl: './signup.html',
})
export class SignUpComponent implements OnInit {
private SignUpSubscription: Subscription;
display:boolean = false;
constructor(private signUpService: SignUpService) {
}
ngOnInit() {
this.SignUpSubscription = 
this.signUpService.openDialogObservable$.subscribe((res) => {
  if (res == 'show') {
    this.display = true;
  }
});
}
showDialog() {
this.display = true;
}
hideDialog() {
this.display = false;
}
}
```

SignUp Html:

```
<div style="background-color: #4cae4c; width: 1000px" class="ui-rtl" 
dir="rtl">
<p-dialog [(visible)]="display" width="200px"  modal="true" 
[responsive]="true" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-
labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
<p-header class="text-center">
  SignUp
</p-header>
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit($event)" #signUpForm="ngForm">

  <div class="group signup form-group" style="width:300px">
    <input #firstName="ngModel" class="form-control" 
  [(ngModel)]="createuser.firstName" name="firstname" type="text" pattern="[\u0600-\u065F\u066A-\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FF][\u0600-\u065F\u066A-\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FF]+" required>
    <span class="highlight"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <label>Name</label>
    </div>
 </form>
</p-dialog>
```

about this html should say I have made it with primeng library for modal and it has used special tag.
In the header component I have a button (Sign up) that the signup component and template and service in a separate folder. I want when user click on that button a modal box will open.
Header component:

```
import {Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output, Input, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {SignUpService} from "../services/signup-service.service";
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs';
@Component({
selector: 'header-component',
templateUrl: './header.component.html',
})
export class HeaderComponent {
private subscription: Subscription;
constructor(private signUpService: SignUpService
) {
}
showDialog() {
this.signUpService.open('show');
}
```

and finally this is the header html:

```
<a type="button" (click)="showDialog()" >Sign Up</a>
```

Problem: When I click on signup button in header the modal box doesn't open.
There is no error but when I put break point in sources it doesn't go to signup.component.ts. What is the problem? How can I fix it?
Thank you for your helping in simple way.
Also there are these two links that similar to my code.
[Parent and children communicate via a service](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service) and
[Example of Component Communication in Angular 2/4](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/01/angular-2-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject)

Answer (score 1):

try the even emitter

First add the data you want to passs:

```
public pdfdisplayAdded$: EventEmitter<PdfDisplay>;

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        this.pdfdisplayAdded$ = new EventEmitter();
    }

    setPdfData(retval: any) {
        this.pdfdisplay = retval;
        this.pdfdisplayAdded$.emit(this.pdfdisplay);
        return this.pdfdisplay;
    }
```

Then subscribe that event where you want to get that data

```
 this.pdfDisplayService.pdfdisplayAdded$.subscribe((data: any) => this.setPdfStatus(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

make  `openDialog` public :

```
export class SignUpService {
  public openDialog = new Subject<any>();
  //...
}
```

and subscribe to `openDialog` :

```
export class SignUpComponent implements OnInit {
  //...
  constructor(private signUpService: SignUpService) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.SignUpSubscription = 
    this.signUpService.openDialog.subscribe((res) => {
      if (res == 'show') {
         this.display = true;
      }
    });
  //...
```